# Support vector machine plotting interpretation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')
clf.fit(X.values, y.values) 

# Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
plot_decision_regions(X=X.values, 
                      y=y.values,
                      clf=clf, 
                      legend=2)

# Update plot object with X/Y axis labels and Figure Title
plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
```

I got following graph for the above code. I intended to use SVC for binary response 0 and 1. I don't understand the plot. I was expecting clear separable space. I was wondering if you could help me to interpret my results. Thanks for your time!

[image]

Comment: I think the graph's fine! Everything is very clear from the graph. You have a space of blue (0) and orange (1) points which are the labels. The colors you see are the regions in which your classifier would predict either 0 (blue) or 1 (orange). From the graph, it seems, you have a lot of data points corresponding to 0 labels and very few labels corresponding to the 1 labels. What else do you expect to interpret?

Comment: @TirthPatel I got this paper useful. https://sebastianraschka.com/pdf/software/mlxtend-latest.pdf Thank you so much! I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are graphing two of the dimensions, so we can't tell if it is more clearly separable in a higher (or different) dimensional space than the graph depicts. Orange triangles in the blue section would be misclassified and vice versa.